# CentOS6 にphp5.6をインストールできない

Tags: php, centos

初歩的な質問ですみません。CentOS6.10にphp5.6をインストールしようとしているのですが、epel,remiを追加してるにもかかわらずどうしてもphp5.3が表示されます。何が足りないのでしょうか？

**コマンド**

```
[root@user yum.repos.d]:324# rpm -qa | grep php
[root@user yum.repos.d]:319# rpm -q epel-release
epel-release-6-8.noarch
[root@user yum.repos.d]:320# rpm -q elrepo-release
elrepo-release-6-8.el6.elrepo.noarch
[root@user yum.repos.d]:321# rpm -q remi-release
remi-release-6.9-3.el6.remi.noarch

[root@user yum.repos.d]:322# ls -l
合計 84
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2024 11月 14 16:27 2018 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  647  6月 26 23:52 2018 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  630  6月 26 23:52 2018 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8854  6月 26 23:52 2018 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  289  6月 26 23:52 2018 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2142  7月 24 03:57 2017 elrepo.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1056 11月  5 12:52 2012 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  957 11月  5 12:52 2012 epel.repo
-rw-r-----  1 root root  150 11月 14 17:00 2018 mariadb.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  446  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-glpi91.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  446  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-glpi92.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  446  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-glpi93.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  456  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-php54.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1314  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-php70.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1314  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-php71.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1314  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-php72.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  750  6月  5 17:25 2018 remi-safe.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2616 11月 14 20:31 2018 remi.repo

[root@j16288at yum.repos.d]:323# yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, versionlock
Repository remi-php56 is listed more than once in the configuration
インストール処理の設定をしています
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.riken.jp
 * elrepo: ftp.ne.jp
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi-php56: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi-safe: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
161 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
依存性の解決をしています
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 のパッケージ: php-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-49.el6 のパッケージ: php-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be インストール
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-49.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。

依存性を解決しました

================================================================================
 パッケージ          アーキテクチャ  バージョン             リポジトリー   容量
================================================================================
インストールしています:
 php                 x86_64          5.3.3-49.el6           base          1.1 M
依存性関連でのインストールをします。:
 php-cli             x86_64          5.3.3-49.el6           base          2.2 M
 php-common          x86_64          5.3.3-49.el6           base          530 k

トランザクションの要約
================================================================================
インストール         3 パッケージ

総ダウンロード容量: 3.8 M
インストール済み容量: 13 M
これでいいですか? [y/N]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`priority` が設定されていて、base, updates の方が remi-php56 よりも優先されているためと思います。
`yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 --disableplugin=priorities install php` でどうでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！コマンド通りに実行してみたらできました！

Answer (score 0):

パッケージ名"php"は"base"リポジトリにも収録されているため、こちらが優先して参照されているのだと思います。
`--disablerepo`で不要なリポジトリは一時的に無効にし、また念のため"remi-php56"と同時に"remi"リポジトリも有効にした状態でインストールを試してみてください。

```
# yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！baseのほうが優先されていたとは迂闊でした。